# Why is my subclassed NSManagedObject not responding to some of the commands used in the MOC's save method?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I initially thought this was a multi-threading oriented crash, so I moved all my actual core data work to the main thread using the MOC's performBLock and performBlockAndWait methods.

All that did is move the crash from where I do my merging to where I call the 'save'.

At this point, I don't even have a clue where to start checking for errors.

It's not multithreading -- all Core Data work is being exported to the main thread.

I recreated all the subclasses, so it shouldn't (theoretically) be a mis-match between the subclass and the entity it represents.

Even more annoying, other than now performing it on the main block, the code I use to update my core data model hasn't changed in several versions, suggesting that I have some kind of serious flaw somewhere deep in my code, and no clue where it is or how to find it.

Any information or advice that can help me track this crash down would be appreciated.

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  NSManagedObjects of entity 'AdBlock' do not support -mutableSetValueForKey: for the property 'currentlyValidAds' with userInfo (null)

2012-09-25 14:50:13.250 CoreApp[1173:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSManagedObjects of entity 'AdBlock' do not support -mutableSetValueForKey: for the property 'currentlyValidAds''
```

AdBlock has a many-to-many, optional, ordered, transient relationship 'currentlyValidAds' with the Advertisement class.  In response to comments, I checked the inverse relationship, which was a to-one, optional transient relationship.  (I've now updated it to be a a many-to-many, option, ordered, transient relationship, but the bug remains).

As requested, the generated code:

AdBlock.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Advertisement;

@interface AdBlock : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * adIndex;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * block_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * seedBlock;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *ads;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSOrderedSet *currentlyValidAds;
@end

@interface AdBlock (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addAdsObject:(Advertisement *)value;
- (void)removeAdsObject:(Advertisement *)value;
- (void)addAds:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeAds:(NSSet *)values;

- (void)insertObject:(Advertisement *)value inCurrentlyValidAdsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
- (void)removeObjectFromCurrentlyValidAdsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
- (void)insertCurrentlyValidAds:(NSArray *)value atIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes;
- (void)removeCurrentlyValidAdsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes;
- (void)replaceObjectInCurrentlyValidAdsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx withObject:(Advertisement *)value;
- (void)replaceCurrentlyValidAdsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes withCurrentlyValidAds:(NSArray *)values;
- (void)addCurrentlyValidAdsObject:(Advertisement *)value;
- (void)removeCurrentlyValidAdsObject:(Advertisement *)value;
- (void)addCurrentlyValidAds:(NSOrderedSet *)values;
- (void)removeCurrentlyValidAds:(NSOrderedSet *)values;
@end


#import "AdBlock.h"
#import "Advertisement.h"
```

AdBlock.m

```
@implementation AdBlock

@dynamic adIndex;
@dynamic block_id;
@dynamic seedBlock;
@dynamic ads;
@dynamic currentlyValidAds;

@end
```

There is also a category that provides some logic -- primarily updating currently valid ads -- but it's not being used in the block of code that's doing the crash, so I'm not including it.

Edit:

I haven't answered the underlying question, but I *have* resolved the crash bug by manually setting the transient value to nil on any objects I deleted.  Not sure why this helped... just a random idea due to sleep deprivation.

Comment: Could you post the source of your subclass?

Comment: Also, double check that the to-many options are properly set for your entity.

Comment: @Maz included requested code.